# How to filter Observable Array in Angular 2.0?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template

I have a simple application which gets information from my API, stores it in memory and then present.

My main component code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
builds$: Observable<BuildInfo[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.builds$ = this.buildService.builds$;
    this.buildService.loadAll();
    ...
}}
```

Template code:

```
.dashboard
.mobile
    .build(*ngFor="let build of (builds$ | async | buildsByGroupFilter:'mobile')")
     | {{build.baseInfo.id}} - {{build.baseInfo.name}} - {{build.status}}
```

buildsByGroupFilter pipe:

```
export class BuildsByGroupFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: BuildInfo[],  arg: string) {
    return items.filter(item => item.baseInfo.group === arg);
}
```

When I run application I get an error that it is not possible to perform transform on undefined object. I don't know how to make a pipe which will wait for data from my service and then transform it and leave only builds that marked as 'mobile'.

Someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
(builds$ | async) | buildsByGroupFilter:'mobile'
```

You should also check for `null` in the pipe

```
transform(items: BuildInfo[],  arg: string) {
    if(items) {
      return items.filter(item => item.baseInfo.group === arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting the same error:
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Unable to get property 'filter' of undefined or null reference